# Animation won't render to file;

Tags: animation

[image]

When I'm in blender and play the animation, it plays fine. But when I render the animation, it just shows a frame or two when i play it.[image]

Comment: Are you rendering in Eevee or cycles?

Comment: Can you upload the project to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If there is physics animation, you need to bake it before rendering.
Here's the guide that explain everything about baking a physics animations: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html

I can confirm that baking the animation is the correct solution.
Please follow these steps:

1. go to "scene properties"
2. open "rigid body world" settings
3. go under "cache"
4. change end frame from 250 to 70 (no need to simulate further your timeline)
5. delete all bakes (just to be sure that if there is something in cache you'll erase it)
6. press "bake all dynamics" to cache your simulation (wait few seconds)
7. render your animation (you can render it frame by frame or render directly the MOV/AVI)

[image]

Comment: I do have rigid body "settings", i tried to use a couple of bake operators, but they all came back with error messages, so that's not the way

Comment: One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer, low quality posts may be removed at some point. Could you edit your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works? Perhaps add a few screenshots illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) otherwise it may be converted into a comment.

Comment: @richrarerefined, not sure what "bake operators" are.
Can you upload the project to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: This is the file I'm working on [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=m5wSVn27" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/m5wSVn27/)

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: pls accept the answer if it was the right one